# i am trying to upload file using react hook form and i used useController function and i am getting error

Tags: reactjs, file, validation, react-hooks

I am creating a multipart form in which uses usecontrol method of react hook form . i declarer default value

```
const methods = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    email: "",
    course: "Enginering",
    program: "B.tech",
    mobielNumber: "",
    dob: "",
    gender: "",
    cityName: "",
    state: "",
    file:"",
  },
});
```

but i am getting file value is null can any one tell me were i have to declare file input so i can  get value .

I seen documentation there they told

> File typed input will need to be managed at the app level due to the
> ability to cancel file selection and FileList object.

what these means where i have to declare it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a day I figure it out that some how we need to explicitly setValue when we post file with useController

And also somehow the *field* object has *value* inside of it, it will get e.target.value as default and it something like ...fakepath/.. which not true because files upload inside e.target.files

```
const { setValue } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
     file: "",
    //.....
  }
})
```

```
const { field: { name, ref } } = useController({name, control, rules, defaultValue});
```

Don't include *value* inside as a result of useController because the *value* inside field gonna cause the error if it use together with *files*

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
   setValue('file', e.target.files);
}

<input name={name} ref={ref} type="file" multiple onChange={handleChange}/>
```

When you submit it, you gonna see the FileList, if not or something like *fakepath* as i said you need to manually setValue to e.target.files